# Mathematical (matrix) notation for a regression model with several dummy variables

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, matrix, notation

I have spent a significant amount of time on this, but my knowledge in Matrix Algebra is still limited. So, I am not sure ...

I have a linear regression model based on $n$ observations. The dependent variable is $y$.

As predictors, there are 10 independent continuous variables + 9 dummy variables (based on a 10-category scale) + 5 dummy variables (based on a 6-category response). The model looks like:
$$
y = \beta_0+\beta_1 \text{C}_1+\beta_2 \text{C}_2+ ...+\beta_{11}\text{dummy}_1+\beta_{12}\text{dummy}_2+ ...+\beta_{19}\text{dummy}_9+\beta_{20}\text{dummy}_{10}+...\beta_{24}\text{dummy}_{14}+\epsilon
$$

Would this be an accurate matrix notation of the above model?
$$
\textbf{y} = \textbf{C}{\beta}+\textbf{S} \gamma + \mathbf{R}\lambda + \textbf{e}
$$

where $\textbf{C}$ is n $\times$  10+1 design matrix with  1s in the first column and 10 other columns containing the continuous predictors , $\textbf{S}$ is the n $\times$  9 matrix containing dummy variables for the 10-category scale,  $\textbf{R}$ is the n $\times$ 5 matrix containing dummy variables for the 6-category response,  ${\beta}$, ${\gamma}$ and ${\lambda}$ are the vectors of parameters, and  $\textbf{e}$ is the error vector.

Is this notation sufficiently accurate? Any references on matrix notation for dummy variables are also very much appreciated.

Sincerely,

Jacob

Comment: Welcome to CV.SE. Yes, you are fine. Good job (+1) Please see my answer below I expand on this a bit more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are fine. Please note that all your categorical vectors will have their first level absorbed within the intercept $\beta_0$, therefore take note of the way the encoding of dummy variables is done. I would say that if anything your notation lends itself nicely to group lasso regularisation; standard lasso solution would only select individual dummy variables instead of whole factors. (check Meier et al.(2007) [The group lasso for logistic regression](ftp://ftp.stat.math.ethz.ch/Manuscripts/buhlmann/lukas-sara-peter.pdf) for more information on that aspect.)

If you are starting and have some queries about notations, standard textbooks on the use of matrices in Statistics are: [*Matrix Algebra Useful for Statistics*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Matrix-Algebra-Useful-Statistics-Probability/dp/1118935144) by Searle and [*Matrix Algebra From a Statistician's Perspective*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Matrix-Algebra-Statisticians-Perspective-Harville/dp/0387783563/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_t_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=67BC3NQEMH56YTVBCY39) by Harvill. Both are consider classics on the matter and you can use them as well-accepted references.
(I also like: [*Matrix Algebra: Theory, Computations, and Applications in Statistics*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Matrix-Algebra-Computations-Applications-Statistics/dp/3319648667/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_t_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=67BC3NQEMH56YTVBCY39) by Gentle, I have used it a lot).

Comment: Remarkably useful. Thank you so much!

Comment: I am glad I could help. If this answer is helpful please consider upvoting it and if it resolves your question marking it as the accepted answer.